# Adding a payload when opening urls with urllib

Tags: python, chat, bots

I created a chatbot that connects to a server and can read messages, now I'm at the point where I need to send messages, requiring request payload (according to the Network tab in Developer tools on google chrome).  My opener consists of nothing but the following:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar
self.cj = CookieJar()
self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
```

To stay and connected and read messages, I do the following, I do the following:

```
def connect(self,settings,xhr):
    xhr_polling = self.get_code(xhr)
    data = self.opener.open("http://chat2-1.wikia.com:80/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/" + xhr_polling + "?name=HairyBot&key=" + 
        settings['chatkey'] + "&roomId=" + str(settings['room']) + "&t=" + timestamp())
    return data.read()
```

Settings consisting of the roomId and chatkey.  The timestamp function creates a timestamp in accordance to what the servers needs (which isn't necessary to know for this question).  Back to the question though, how can a payload be added to the opener to send a message to the chat?

Comment: Request payload? Do you mean a POST request?

Comment: Ah yes, POST request. I misinterpreted what Chrome is showing me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a payload", but presumably it's just another form variable named `payload`. If so, you send it the same way you do any other form variable, and you're already sending a bunch—`roomId`, `t`, etc.

One way of sending form variables is by URL-encoding them, tacking them onto the query string, and sending a GET request. That's what you're doing now. (It would be better to use proper `urllib` methods instead of hacking it together with string concatenation, but the end result is the same.)

The other way is by sending a POST body. The [`urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) explains how to do this, and there are plenty of good examples online, but basically all you have to do is call `urllib.urlencode()` on your name-value pairs, then pass the result as the second argument (or as a keyword argument named `data`) to the `open` call.

In other words, something like this:

```
data = self.opener.open("http://chat2-1.wikia.com:80/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/" + xhr_polling,
                        urllib.urlencode(("name", "HairyBot"),
                                         ("key", settings['chatkey']),
                                         ("roomId", str(settings['room']),
                                         ("key", settings['chatkey']),
                                         ("t", timestamp()),
                                         ("payload", payload)))
```

Or, if you prefer, most servers will allow you to send some parameters on the query string and others in the POST data, so you can leave your existing code alone and just make one change:

```
data = self.opener.open("http://chat2-1.wikia.com:80/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/" + xhr_polling + "?name=HairyBot&key=" + 
    settings['chatkey'] + "&roomId=" + str(settings['room']) + "&t=" + timestamp(),
    urllib.urlencode(("payload", payload)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, I recommend use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library. It makes this stuff really simple:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()  # For connection pooling

def connect(self,settings,xhr):
    xhr_polling = self.get_code(xhr)
    request = session.get('http://chat2-1.wikia.com:80/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/' + xhr_polling, params={
        'name': 'HairyBot',
        'key': settings['chatkey'],
        'roomId': settings['room'],
        't': timestamp()
    })

    return request.text
```

If you want to send a POST request instead, just change `get` to `post` and add some data:

```
def connect(self,settings,xhr):
    xhr_polling = self.get_code(xhr)
    request = session.post('http://chat2-1.wikia.com:80/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/' + xhr_polling, params={
        'name': 'HairyBot',
        'key': settings['chatkey'],
        'roomId': settings['room'],
        't': timestamp()
    }, data={
        'key': 'value'
    })

    return request.text
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not handle his cookiejar. Not that it's hard to do that with `requests`, but he's already got the code for doing that in `urllib2`, and what he wants to do now isn't actually any harder in `urllib2` than in `requests`.

Comment: @abarnert: Requests handles cookies by default, so there isn't really any need to manually setup a CookieJar.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize he was just using the default cookiejar, rather than loading an explicit one. In that case, yeah, he doesn't have to do anything. But still, the code isn't that much different here. `requests` lets you skip the `urllib.urlencode()` and the explicit cookiejar; `urllib2` lets you skip the explicit `post`, but otherwise, they're pretty much identical.